# Can't display the fetch data

Tags: php, reactjs

I am new in ReactJS so fetching data isn't my expertise, so I'm trying to learn ReactJS with my PHP Native. The problem is fetching data is difficult for me. This code below there's no error but it won't display my data.

It can't display in my UI, the data is stayed in console(Network -> Response), i tried everything still can't output it. Can someone help?

```
import './Timesheet.css';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Table, Container, Button, } from 'react-bootstrap';


const Timesheet = () => {
    const [item, setItem] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("http://localhost/WaterRefillingStation/app/controllers/timesheet_controller.php")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(
            (result) => {
                setItem(result);
            }
        )
    }, []) 
    return ( 
        <Container fluid>     
            <div className="d_flex my-4, text-uppercase">
                <h1>
                    Timesheet Screen
                </h1>
            </div>

            <div className="float-end, tryy"  >
                <Button variant="success" size="md">Time IN</Button>{' '}
                <Button variant="secondary" size="md">Time OUT</Button>{' '}
                <Button variant="danger" size="md">Logout</Button>
            </div>
            
            <Table striped bordered hover size="md" variant="dark" responsive="xl" >
                <thead className="thead-dark">
                    <tr style={{textAlign: "center"}}>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Profile Picture</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Designation</th>
                        <th>Time IN</th>
                        <th>Time OUT</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {item.map(item => (
                        <tr key={item}>
                            <td>{item.userID}</td>
                            <td>{item.birthday}</td>
                            <td>{item.profpic}</td>
                            <td>{item.lastname}</td>
                            <td>{item.firstname}</td>
                            <td>{item.designation}</td>
                            <td>{item.created_at}</td>
                            <td>{item.updated_at}</td>
                        </tr>
                    ))}
                </tbody>
            </Table> 
           
        </Container>
    );
}
 
export default Timesheet;
```

Comment: Please show your response

Comment: Hello, response in console?

Comment: @Newbie yes add your response data

Comment: Like this?
{"userID":"24","roleID":"2","firstname":"Nobita","lastname":"Damulag","email":"nobita@gmail.com","address":"123123","age":"32","designation":"Delivery","contact_number":"9999999","birthday":"2021-09-09","validID":null,"profpic":null,"password":"$2y$10$v2MWhzxvwxROd94gXEBqHOiPx1\/JX6wYz8pS1zwxffw","user_status":"1","user_delete":"0","created_at":"2021-09-06 08:59:10","updated_at":"2021-09-06 08:59:10"}

Comment: Sorry, new in ReactJS.

Comment: it is ok, do you receive this data in your react code?

Comment: Please show `console.log(result)` before `setItem(result);`

Comment: @Viet there's an array in console

Comment: Please show this

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems that you have used `.map` in the wrong way. You can use it for an array, not an object. use this instead:

```
return ( 
        <Container fluid>     
            <div className="d_flex my-4, text-uppercase">
                <h1>
                    Timesheet Screen
                </h1>
            </div>

            <div className="float-end, tryy"  >
                <Button variant="success" size="md">Time IN</Button>{' '}
                <Button variant="secondary" size="md">Time OUT</Button>{' '}
                <Button variant="danger" size="md">Logout</Button>
            </div>
            
            <Table striped bordered hover size="md" variant="dark" responsive="xl" >
                <thead className="thead-dark">
                    <tr style={{textAlign: "center"}}>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Profile Picture</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Designation</th>
                        <th>Time IN</th>
                        <th>Time OUT</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                        <tr key={item}>
                            <td>{item.userID}</td>
                            <td>{item.birthday}</td>
                            <td>{item.profpic}</td>
                            <td>{item.lastname}</td>
                            <td>{item.firstname}</td>
                            <td>{item.designation}</td>
                            <td>{item.created_at}</td>
                            <td>{item.updated_at}</td>
                        </tr>
                </tbody>
            </Table> 
           
        </Container>
```

if you want to have a table for each user (for example), you should to provide data like below in your backend:

```
{ 
data:[
   { USER1 Info},
   { USER2 Info},
   // so on
]
}
```

Comment: I tried but the data is not yet display, it still in Network>Response

Comment: try showing your data using `<h1>{item.userID}</h1>` instead of table to test if your table works correctly. let me know the result

Comment: it has an error: Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <h1> cannot appear as a child of <tr>.

Comment: no, replace all `return <Container ...>` section with `return <h1>{item.userID}</h1>`

Comment: The page is blank, no displayy